# Como saber que uma pergunta recebeu atualização ou comentários?

Tags: debate, respostas, comentários

Como posso eu saber se um post recebeu comentário ou atualização na resposta? Só pelo número de visitas não dá.

Comment: Isto resolveria? http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1386/e-possivel-receber-notificacoes-de-perguntas-especificas